# How to change element within iframed content from another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im iframing a store locator app that uses google map api. The app is batchgeo and you can iframe it like this:

```
    <iframe src="https://batchgeo.com/map/50365d0f4d174d9c57c6b3a70217bfd2" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="550" style="border:1px solid #aaa;"></iframe>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to remove the image that is within the iframe:

```
<img id="bgLogo" src="//d27ixrd8sdmf11.cloudfront.net/images/bg-logo-only-60x60.png?v=2" width="30" height="30" align="absmiddle" alt="Make maps with BatchGeo">
```

Obviously I tried to do this with jquery and it didn't work:

```
$( "#bgLogo" ).remove();
```

I suspect this is becuase of the same origin policy. Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: You can't; you're exactly right, it's because of the same origin policy.

Comment: I suspect you already found one or more of the hundreds of similar questions here and are expecting a different answer than all the ones that said you can't do it